# For statement don't works in batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, command, cmd, move

`for %%i in (foo bar) do @move %%i dir`

This is the content of the batch file. It have to move the file to dir. But it returns error,

`C:\>∩╗┐for %i in (foo bar) do @move %i dir
'∩╗┐for' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

What it the character `∩╗┐` ? I checked with notepad++ and I don't find any hidden char in that batch file.

Comment: Do you have `@echo off` at the beginning of your file?

Comment: Don't have it, I've `pause`. And tried even `@echo off`. Don't work.

Comment: What is the contents of the file? `∩╗┐` isn't a char that batch will understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have UTF-8 encoding set in notepad++
You will need to change it to **UTF-8 without BOM** or ANSI in order to work with cmd (batch)

Strange characters you see at the beginning is BOM - byte order mark code used by UTF

Comment: Exactly! I've set UTF-8. Done the job & working fine. Anyway, is there anyway to change this code to work vice versa? I mean move files from `dir` to parent folder without prefixing  directory name in every file-name? any means by variables?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question... this will move file(s) to **its** parent dir `for %%I in (foo bar) do move %%I %%~dpI..` Search online and if you cannot find an answer ask another question on SO please, as comments should not be used for this

Comment: Thanks. It neither give output nor result.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that comes to mind is encoding. Make sure it's saved in format that cmd will understand (got similar issues when my .cmd file was saved as Unicode Big Endian. Could reproduce your error by saving file as UTF-8. Tried to use ANSI instead.

HTH
Bartek

Comment: Fixed; I've used Unicode-8 without BOM option. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some hidden characters in it. Try retyping it into a new file. The `∩╗┐` definitely shouldn't be there.

Comment: So...you did have hidden characters, the BOM used by UTF.

Comment: Even in BOM encoding, I didn't see that char. Hence I said, there is no hidden char.

Comment: Notepad++ knows what to do with the characters, so you won't see them.  The Windows command interpreter doesn't know what to do with them and tries to treat them as a command.